# No regex pattern seems to solve my problem

Tags: regex

I'm dealing with a "greedy" regular expression, which is trying to match as much text as possible. In this case, it's matching the first #Q and the last #/Q it encounters, rather than the pair that is closest to each other.

I tried (and so many patterns):

```py
MATCHES = re.findall(r"#Q.*?#/Q", original_text, re.DOTALL)
```

original_text:

```
Y8hg8yg

#Q
Toy Story::Cowboy?

#Q
Hello
?
World!

#Q
Toy ==Story==

#Q
This

is



Test
#/Q

#Q
Anither problem

djdjdjdidjfi8s8
```

I'm only trying to capture:

```
#Q
This

is



Test
#/Q
```

But it always captures:

```
#Q
Toy Story::Cowboy?

#Q
Hello
?
World!

#Q
Toy ==Story==

#Q
This

is



Test
#/Q
```

No matter how hard I try, I'm stuck.

Comment: Maybe add code about how you try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
#Q(?![\s\S]*?#Q[\s\S]*?#\/Q)[\s\S]+#\/Q
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/yssaS6/latest

---

##### EXPLANATION

`#Q` matches `#Q` literally

`(?!..:)` from here do not match if...

- `[\s\S]*?` anything, including linebreaks (lazy)
- `#Q` but another `#Q`
- `[\s\S]*?#\/Q` before you encounter a `#/Q`

`[\s\S]+` then match anything

`#\/Q` up until `#/Q`

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm kind of disappointed because it looks like I've lost my critical thinking skills, unlike before, but thank you again for your kindness and wisdom!